# Unmount React Parent without Unmounting Child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

Is it possible for a React component's parent to be unmounted without the child being unmounted? What work arounds exist to achieve this result? Surely there must be some (potentially hacky) way to do this.

**Example**

When this:

```
<Parent>
  <Child/>
</Parent>
```

changes to this:

```
<Child/>
```

I would like `Parent`'s lifecycle method `componentWillUnmount` to be called without `Child`'s lifecycle method `componentWillUnmount` being called.

I recognize this may not be possible but was wondering if anyone had a creative solution to this problem.

**Update**

Here's my specific use case (hopefully I do a good enough job explaining this):

I have a higher order component which doesn't introduce any new dom elements but essentially just introduces some new context for the child component. The child component renders slightly differently depending on whether or not this context is present. Unfortunately when I remove and add the parent a new instance of the child is created and it unmounts/remounts. The only issue with this unmounting and remounting is that the child element does some dom measurements to decide whether or not to show a horizontal scroll bar and overflow menu for some of it's elements. When it unmounts/remounts there is an unsightly flash of this menu.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the use case for this?

Comment: if you have parent and child only, theres no way to render child if parent is not being rendered. You would need something like App->Routes and conditional render like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the rendering logic. For example inside your render function:

```
  if (showParent) {
    return (
    <Parent>
        <Child/>
    </Parent>);
  } else{
    return <Child/>;
  }
```

Then whenever the boolean `showParent` changes the component renders differently.

The super-parent object, calling this render() , should store the state in order to update them and preserve the child (and parent, in case you want to switch it back on).

Therefore it should also contain the state of the child, in order for it to be kept. In other words: move the model hierarchically up to the super parent.

Comment: You need to include a mechanism to also pass the internal state from one to the other if you want to do this

Comment: Indeed the super-parent, calling this render() should store the state. It is the only way

Comment: I think this would technically create a new instance of `<Child/>` with the same props, so if the child has any state it would be lost. But I think you're right that it's the only way.

Comment: Yeah... exactly my thoughts... +1